# How to convert a String line to class

Tags: c#, linq

I converted class objet to String line

As in the following example

```
    public class Person
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"{ID}|{Name}|{Surname}|{Address}";
        }
    }

        Person person = new Person();
        person.Name = "test1";
        person.Surname = "test2";
        person.Address = "test3";

        var _String = person.ToString();
        Console.WriteLine(_String);
```

This is the output

0|test1|test2|test3

I want to convert the line (0|test1|test2|test3) to class objet

What is the best way to do this to dotnet standard 2.0

Comment: Welcome to SO. Try to provide a [mre] of what you have tried. You'll learn more from getting input to what you've tried than asking for a solution with no basis

Comment: Thank you, sir. I think this is not possible :  Person result = _String.Split('|');  I am a beginner and I apologize to you please help

Comment: After you split, assign the first item to id, the second to Name, etc.

Comment: If you have the option, there are better ways of serializing objects, like to json or xml.

Comment: Person person1 = new Person() { Name = _String.Split('|')[0] } etc..

Comment: @Miraziz I would not recommend repeating the split for each property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check what `_String.Split('|')` returns, you'll see that it gives a `string[]`. This string-array contains each part of `_String` on either sides of the `|` characters, so:

```
var person = new Person()
{
    ID = 1,
    Name = "James",
    Surname = "Smith",
    Address = "James's Road 123"
};

var _String = person.ToString(); // "1|James|Smith|James's Road 123"

var stringSplit = _String.Split("|"); // ["1", "James", "Smith", "James's Road 123"]
```

Now, you have all 4 parts of the person you want to create, so now you can recreate the person:

```
var recreatedPerson = new Person()
{
    ID = stringSplit[0],
    Name = stringSplit[1],
    Surname = stringSplit[2],
    Address = stringSplit[3]
}
```

You might notice the first line in the person will fail (`ID = stringSplit[0]`) because `stringSplit[0]` is a `string`, but `ID` expects an `int`. So to convert a `string` into an `int` we need to parse it:

```
ID = int.Parse(stringSplit[0])
```

Remember, if you do not give the original person an `ID` the string-array will not have an ID either, in which case the above parsing will fail. But I'll let you think about how you could handle that.

**EDIT:** as stated in the comments to your question, if this is not just a little exercise in learning C#, and if you are really looking for a proper way of turning an object into a string and vice versa, you should look into serializing your objects using JSON, XML or similar.